# How do I Insert Record MVVM through WCF

Tags: wcf, mvvm, light

I’m new in MVVM Pattern (Using Galasoft MVVM Light toolkit). I’ve created a Test Project where I want to fetch some records from Database through WCF. This is working fine but I’ve failed to insert new record from View; Here is My Code:

**Database**

Table Name: TestUser (First Name, LastName)

**WCF (NWCustomer)**

Two Methods

```
Public List<TestUser> GetAllUsers() [“LINQ2SQL Operation”] 
Public bool AddUser(TestUser testuser) 

Public bool AddUser(TestUser testuser)
{

        try

        {
                    using (DBDataContext db = new DBDataContext())
                    {
                                TestUser test = new TestUser()
                                {
                                            FirstName = testuser.FirstName,
                                            LastName = testuser.LastName
                                };
                                db.TestUser.InsertOnSubmit(test);
                                db.SubmitChanges();
                    }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
                    return false;
        }
        return true;
}
```

**Silverlight Project**

***MODEL consists***

ITestUserService.cs

*TestUserService.cs*

```
   public void AddTestTable(TestTableViewModel testuser, Action<bool> callback)
   {
       NWCustomerClient client = new NWCustomerClient("BasicHttpBinding_NWCustomer");
       client.AddTestUserCompleted += (s, e) =>
       {
           var userCallback = e.UserState as Action<bool>;
           if (userCallback == null)
           {
               return;
          }
           if (e.Error == null)
           {
               userCallback(e.Result);
               return;
           }
           userCallback(false);
       };      

       client.AddTestUserAsync(testuser.Model);
   }
```

**VIEWMODEL**

***TestUserViewModel***

```
   public TestUser User
   {
       get;

       private set;
   } 

  public const string DirtyVisibilityPropertyName = "DirtyVisibility";
  private Visibility _dirty = Visibility.Collapsed;
  public Visibility DirtyVisibility
   {
       get
       {
           return _dirty;
       }

       set
       {
           if (_dirty == value)
           {
               return;
           }

           _dirty = value;
           RaisePropertyChanged(DirtyVisibilityPropertyName);
       }

   }

   public TestUserViewModel (TestUser user)
   {
       User = user;
       user.PropertyChanged += (s, e) =>
           {
               DirtyVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
           };
   }
```

***MainViewModel***

```
   public ObservableCollection<TestUserViewModel> TestTables
   {
       get;
      private set;
   }

   public const string ErrorMessagePropertyName = "ErrorMessage";
   private string _errorMessage = string.Empty;
   public string ErrorMessage
   {
       get
       {
            return _errorMessage;
       }
       set
       {
           if (_errorMessage == value)
           {
               return;
           }

           _errorMessage = value;
           RaisePropertyChanged(ErrorMessagePropertyName);
       }
   }

   private     ITestUserService _service;
   public RelayCommand< TestUserViewModel> AddTestUserRecord
   {
       get;
       private set;
   }

   public MainTestTableViewModel (ICustomerService service)
   {
       _service = service;
       TestTables = new ObservableCollection<TestTableViewModel>();
       service.GetAllTestTable(HandleResult);
   } 

   private void HandleResult(IEnumerable<TestTable> result, Exception ex)
   {
       TestTables.Clear();
       if (ex != null)
       {
           //Error
           return;
       }

       if (result == null)
       {
          return;
       }

       foreach (var test in result)
       {
           var table = new TestTableViewModel(test);
           TestTables.Add(table);
       }
   }
```

**XAML**

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
   <StackPanel>
                                <TextBox Text="FirstName" />

                                <TextBox Text="LastName" />

                                <Button Content="Add Record" Command="{Binding AddTestUserRecord}" />

           </StackPanel>

</Grid>
```

I want to add records into TestTable (Database Table). How do I insert record? In XAML two text box and a button control is present.

Thanking you.

DG

Comment: In `MainViewModel` constructor: `AddTestUserRecord = new RelayCommand(tuVM => _service.AddTestTable(tuVM, [callback]));`

Comment: No call back function for AddTestUserRecord ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the Text property of your textboxes to string properties on your ViewModel, when the "execute" method of your AddTestUserRecord command is invoked, just fetch the properties and call your logic to insert the values into your Database.

Answer (score 0):

First change ur xml. 
AS So Many Goblins said:= ***You need to bind the Text property of your textboxes to string properties on your ViewModel*** 
ur should look like this

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">   <StackPanel    
                <TextBox Text="{Binding FirstName,Mode=TwoWay" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding FirstName,Mode=TwoWay" />
                <Button Content="Add Record" Command="{Binding AddTestUserRecord}" />   </StackPanel> </Grid>
```

In ur view Model code should be like this.

```
Private _FirstName As String    Public Property FirstName() As String
    Get
        Return _FirstName 
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _FirstName = value RaisePropertyChanged(FirstName)
    End Set
End Property



Private _LastName As String   Public Property LastName() As String
    Get
        Return _LastName 
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _LastName = value RaisePropertyChanged(LastName)
    End Set
End Property 


 Private _AddTestUserRecord As ICommand
Public Property AddTestUserRecord() As ICommand
    Get
        If _AddTestUserRecordIs Nothing Then
            _AddTestUserRecord= New RelayCommand(Nothing, AddressOf AddUser)
        End If
        Return _rad_Map_Loaded
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As ICommand)
        _AddTestUserRecord= value
    End Set
End Property

Public Sub AddUser()
   Try

Using db As New DBDataContext()
    Dim test As New TestUser() With { _
        Key .FirstName = me.FirstName, _
        Key .LastName = me.LastName _
    }
    db.TestUser.InsertOnSubmit(test)
    db.SubmitChanges()
End Using Catch ex As Exception     Return False  End Try    End Sub
```

The code is not well formatted and also in vb but it will give u fair idea about what u have to do.